# Looking for method name by address in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, methods, addressof

This is not really a question because I found out how to do this.
Start with a delegate.

```
Public Delegate Sub PageFunction()
```

Then, define a function, for example:

```
Sub Action()
End Sub
```

Then you can get the function name from its address, like:

```
    Dim x As PageFunction = AddressOf Action

    Response.Write( x.Method.Name )
```

Comment: You can ask a *question* and then *answer* it - that fits better into the Q&A format here (and is explicitly allowed)